# Variable running time of a C program

Tags: c, optimization, memory, sse

My (simd) implementation takes varied amount of time, though it is run for fixed input. The running time varies between say 100 million clock cycles to 120 million clock cycles. The program calls a function around 600 times, and the most expensive part of the function is in it memory is accessed ~2000 times. Thus, overall memory involvement in quite high in my program.

Is the variation in running time due to memory access patterns/initial memory contents?

I used valgrind to analyze profile my program. It shows each memory access takes about 8 instructions. Is this normal?

Following is the piece of code (function) that is called 600 times. Mulprev[32][20] is the array which is accessed most number of times.

```
j = 15;  
u3v = _mm_set_epi64x (0xF, 0xF);
while (j + 1)  
{

    l = j << 2;  
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        val1v   = _mm_load_si128 ((__m128i *) &elm1v[i]);       
        uv  = _mm_and_si128 (_mm_srli_epi64 (val1v, l), u3v);
        u1  = _mm_extract_epi16 (uv, 0);
        u2  = _mm_extract_epi16 (uv, 4) + 16;

        for (ival = i, ival1 = i + 1, k = 0; k < 20; k += 2, ival += 2, ival1 += 2)
        {
            temp11v = _mm_load_si128 ((__m128i *) &mulprev[u1][k]); 
            temp12v = _mm_load_si128 ((__m128i *) &mulprev[u2][k]);

            val1v   = _mm_load_si128 ((__m128i *) &res[ival]);
            val2v   = _mm_load_si128 ((__m128i *) &res[ival1]); 

            bv  = _mm_xor_si128 (val1v, _mm_unpacklo_epi64 (temp11v, temp12v));
            av  = _mm_xor_si128 (val2v, _mm_unpackhi_epi64 (temp11v, temp12v));

            _mm_store_si128 ((__m128i *) &res[ival], bv);                                   
            _mm_store_si128 ((__m128i *) &res[ival1], av); 
        }
    }

    if (j == 0)
        break;
    val0v = _mm_setzero_si128 ();

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        testv   = _mm_load_si128 ((__m128i *)  &res[i]);
        val1v   = _mm_srli_epi64 (testv, 60);
        val2v   = _mm_xor_si128  (val0v, _mm_slli_epi64 (testv, 4));
        _mm_store_si128 (&res[i], val2v);
        val0v   = val1v;
    }
    j--;
}
```

I want to reduce the computation time of my program. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to post the actual code if you want help optimising it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing almost no computation in between loads and stores, hence your execution time will most likely be dominated by the cost of I/O to/from cache/memory. Even worse, your data set appears to be relatively small. Probably the only way you can optimise this further is to improve the memory access pattern (make accesses sequential where possible, and ensure that cache lines are not wasted, etc) and/or combine these operations with other code which operates on the same data set before/after this routine (so that the cost of loads/stores in amortised somewhat).

EDIT: note that I gave a very similar answer when you asked much the same question for an apparently earlier version of this routine: [How to make the following code faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450102/how-to-make-the-following-code-faster) - you seem to have missed the point that your main performance problem here is memory access, not computation.

Answer (score 1):

Computers are complicated. Could easily be background processes interfering in some way. It is hard to suggest improvements without additional info. Generally, the best optimizations are the high-level ones. Choose better algorithms, minimize expensive operations. If you don't think there is much room for improvement there, don't expect too high gains. You say that your memory accesses take a lot of cycles. I could suggest that you use restricted pointers where possible, but it's hard to give general advice on optimization issues. You sort of have to try out things yourself.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing (no guarantee what processes get run when in a multitasking OS, if they have the same priority), but then I read this: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.cycles  Apparently, cycles in valgrind are not the same thing as processor cycles(?)

Comment: @esaj that link is describing graph cycles http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory) in the call graph of the program.

Answer (score 0):

8 cycles for a memory access is quite a long time. Another process might be having a negative impact on the CPU caches causing your program a lot of cache-misses, or if your memory is dynamically allocated you might be seeing unaligned memory access penalties.

It could be anything.

Comment: Can you give me a typical L1 cache read time with assumed hit? If the data is in cache, is it guaranteed that fetch time would be similar irrespective of its location on the cache. Any references?

Comment: 8 cycles is *NOT* a long time for a memory access. In case of a cache miss going all the way to the DRAM can take 100 cycles and more on a modern CPU.

Comment: @anup, @Axel: Latency for an L1 hit on modern CPUs is typically ~4 cycles (see the Intel Optimization Guides, or processor-specific documentation for more detail).  It's worth noting that anup actually said "[Valgrind] shows each memory access takes about 8 instructions".  Instructions are not cycles; a modern Intel CPU can potentially retire 4 instructions per cycle so "8 instructions" might actually mean just a couple cycles, in line with an L1 hit.  I'm not familiar with Valgrind however, so I don't know how it actual does its measurements.

Comment: @Stephen: I was talking about *DRAM*, not cache.